# Other ways to display tabular data?

Tags: 2013, office-365, design, data, user-experience

Right now I'm just using an Excel web part but it's a bit cluttered.  I just need a simple way to store points of data similar to what you see below.

[image]

obviously I don't need all the extraneous columns, row numbers, sheet tabs, etc.  What are my options?

Comment: Why are you using excel instead of a SharePoint list?

Comment: I don't know.  How would I set up a list to do this?  I use a list for tasks, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new custom list, then add a column for your data points. Then when you add this list as a web part (or just view the list itself) you should see Title and Data columns.